# In server react js applicatioin, refreshing is not okay with route path in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In local testing , it is okay refresh is okay, but in server after refresh , it can't find the route path...
The requested URL /TourGuideListMode was not found on this server is as shown as error.

My App.js is like that.

```
const App = () =>(
    <Switch>

          <Route exact={true} path='/' component= {Home} />
          <Route path='/TourGuideListMode' component={TourGuideList} />
          <Route path='/Login' component={Login} />
    </Switch>
)
```

My index.js is like that.

```
  ReactDOM.render(

       <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
       </BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Refresh make me crazy.. Solve for me

Comment: How are you serving your app ?

Comment: Could you show how you handle it on the server?

Comment: Your apache server may have to redirect all routes `/*` to your app

Comment: in my package.json ..is like that...  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }